# Did the apostles believe that God is unique, eternal, infinite, omnipotent, immutable, "simple", spirit, and personal?

Tags: apostles, belief

I am pretty sure the Jewish Bible (OT) gives these characteristics to God.

Examples.

1) God is unique: Is 45:18

2) God is infinite and omnipotent: Ps 135:5-6

3) God is eternal: Is 40:28

4) God is beyond measurement, He is not limited to space:
1 Kgs 8:27

6) God is immutable, He does not change...ever: Ps 102:26:28

7) God is utterly simple, pure spirit: Ex 20:4 (a negative statement showing that He cannot be represented)

8) God is personal: Jer 31:3

Well and good.

I also know that the apostles were various types of Jewish, who Jesus called. So. Did the apostles still hold to the "attributes of God"?  They didn't stop believing that God had all those attribs, did they?

Comment: Why do you think they might not have?

Comment: Hmm is Ex 20:4 really a good argument for "utterly simple, pure spirit" OT God? It only says not to create idols (of anything). Can we really deduce anything about the nature of God from this? This seems consistent with: 1. utterly simple, pure spirit 2. utterly incomprehensible complexity which can't be captured in image 3. just wants to avoid idolatry, no message whatsoever regarding nature. There surely have to better arguments for "utterly simple, pure spirit" than that one.

Comment: @curiousdannii  Maybe I'm just chasing my tail here, but I think that consistency with the OT conception of God should be important in the establishment of Christianity, even while the idea of a triad in the Godhead is emerging.  Can we show that continuity beyond doubt?

Comment: @rje Do you mean to find "biblical basis for the Trinity in the OT"? Or do you want an historical study on these characteristics of God limited to the Apostolic era? Reconciling Christianity with ancient Judaism is a big topic. I don't think you're chasing your tail, as much as opening a can of worms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apostles believed the SAME God revealed in the OT **fulfilled his promise** by sending Jesus, His Son.  The promise He delivered through the prophets as well as hinted through His inspiration to the writers of the Wisdom books such as the Psalms, Job, etc. so the NT books are replete with OT references.

I think the variety of Jewish schools of thoughts (the primary ones being the Pharisees, the Sadducee, the Essenes, the Zealots) did not differ when it came to characterizing who their God was, possessing the attributes of the LORD (*yhwh*) in the OT.  Furthermore, when the apostles began to realize how Jesus's essence was actually the same as the God that they have been worshiping in the Temple, it's NOT necessary for them to discard / demote those attributes.

Instead, they were delighted that now they could see God **face to face**, something that was scary (they could die) or prohibited.  If you place yourself in the apostles's shoes, it's like the far distant King whom you so much revered and longed for His presence in the world suddenly came for a visit to YOUR home and personally called you to be one of the twelve.  It's like Queen Elizabeth visited your home in rural England disguised as a regular person but who later revealed herself to be the Queen **AND** adopted you as her son.  What an honor!  Did you believe her and accept the adoption?  Or did you refuse to believe she was truly the Queen, like Judas?

After resurrection, the apostles were emboldened and were willing to suffer and die like Jesus for the SAME OT God, like the Maccabean heroes who were martyred less than 200 years earlier.  In their evangelistic ministries (Paul being the most documented in the NT), do we see them relinquishing the attributes you mentioned?  Let's see.  I'm adding an NT verse to your list.  They may not be the best NT verse for the attribute, but close enough.

1. God is unique: [Is 45:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isa+45%3A18&version=NLT)  [Acts 14:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+14%3A15&version=NLT)
2. God is infinite and omnipotent: [Ps 135:5-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ps+135%3A5-6&version=NLT) [Rom 11:33-35](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rom+11%3A33-35&version=NLT)
3. God is eternal: [Is 40:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Is+40%3A28&version=NLT)  [Rev 1:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rev+1%3A8&version=NLT)
4. God is beyond measurement, He is not limited to space: [1 Kgs 8:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Kgs+8%3A27&version=NLT)  [Acts 17:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+17%3A24&version=NLT) (In fact, I think Paul quoted 1 Kgs 8:27 !)
5. (you skipped a number :-) )
6. God is immutable, He does not change...ever: [Ps 102:26-28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ps+102%3A26-28&version=NLT) [Heb 6:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=heb+6%3A17&version=NLT)
7. God is utterly simple, pure spirit: [Ex 20:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=+Ex+20%3A4&version=NLT) (a negative statement showing that He cannot be represented)  [1 Cor 10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+cor+10&version=NLT) (here Paul warned the Corinthians not to follow the example of the Israelites in the wilderness, worshiping idol)
8. God is personal: [Jer 31:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=jer+31%3A3&version=NLT)  [John 3:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+3%3A16&version=NLT)

I hope I addressed your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: In fact, if they didn't see God as the God of the OT, they wouldn't have a basis for worshipping Christ, would they?

Comment: Absolutely right; it's crucial that the God of the NT is the same with the God of the NT, and the early church fought hard to combat heresies that said otherwise (like the Gnostics or the [Marcionites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcionism)).

Comment: "It's crucial that the God of the OT is the same as the God of the NT."

Quotable!

Answer (score 0):

Q: Did the apostles still hold to the attributes of God ?

A: No they realized that Christ Jesus  is the Way,Truth, Light - i.e, realizing that he is the perfect image of the father.

Q: They didn't stop believing that God had all those attrib, did they ?

A: Of Course Not. I recommend reading The Holy Bible with the Lord Christ Yeshua in mind. No one can come to the Father but, by him. While studying and seeing these characteristics rather than attempting to finding those listed, as it should be self-evident look for the characteristics provided by Jesus Christ. In doing so, you realize that Jesus Christ is the Perfect Image of the Father. In which you then realize that he is the Father. Hope I was able to help.

Comment: @AlgoLanda your answer would be more solid if you could indicate Bible portions that support your answer

Comment: Genesis 1:26, John 14:6 - When you read the bible with Christ our Lord in mind it's simplistic & beautiful. That by using these his characteristics you see the Father.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The New Testament doesn't really tell much about how the apostles changed their view of God, beyond showing that Christ is part of the Godhead, does it?